# Recover funds from a smart contract wrote a mistake by developers

Tags: solidity, blockchain, private-blockchain

Our developer has deployed a errored smart contract for a autopool plan, but the plan was expired 3 years ago. Users transfered funds to this contract. I am wondering if I can get back these funds somehow, since I own this contract. How to send the balance to the owner address.

This is the contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x22e84cb17a55d618138911549e28310a84f888de/

Please help me friends! contact: naga.ngl@gmail.com